# A fable in which pigs with human heads are born because the swineherds had no women with them

Tags: identification-request, short-stories

I am trying to find a fable I read a long time ago (some 40 years ago, maybe), probably in a collection of short stories / fables, probably in Spanish.
From what I have been searching so far, it seems it isn't one of the classic Greek-roman fables, though it was written in Aesop's fables style - rural setting, countrymen,  small village, nothing "modern".
In the story the problem was that there were born several pigs with human heads and nobody could explain the reason or what it meant - until somebody suggested a solution (and indirectly the cause): let the men who take care of the pigs in the fields have their women with them (when they go to the fields).
The story stuck me because it was the first reference I read that pointed to zoophilia  (I'm not saying it is the earliest reference to zoophilia there is, but the first I came across while growing up).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you be misremembering pigs instead of lambs? If so, it appears Phaedrus has such story attributed to Aesop:
[ÆSOP AND THE FARMER](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/25512/25512-h/25512-h.htm#riley_III_III).

Comment: Yes - that's definitively it ! Thank you so much

Comment: I have just found that Plutarch has a similar story in his 'DINNER-PARTY OF THE SEVEN SAGES' (https://www.gutenberg.org/files/62618/62618-h/62618-h.htm#chap01 149 C): " ... a baby thing which he told us was the offspring of a mare. The upper parts, as far as the neck and arms, were human, the lower parts equine; its voice when it cried was that of a new-born child..." ... "My own advice is to be more careful as to your herdsmen." - Another edition [Delphi Complete Works of Plutarchus] adds "or else that you should provide wives for them "